# How do I test the redmine mail-receiver

Tags: redmine

I am trying to get the `rdm-mailhandler.rb` mail-receiver to work on our redmine installation. But I get

```
Posting to https://redmine.myserver.com/mail_handler...
Response received: 422 Request was denied by your Redmine server. 
Possible reasons: email is sent from an invalid email address or is missing some information.
```

It's the same result if I run it with `fetchmail` or if I run it commandline like:

```
echo hello | sudo -Hu redmine /usr/bin/ruby /storage/_redmine/redmine/extra/mail_handler/rdm-mailhandler.rb --url=https://redmine.myserver.com/ --key=SECRET --no-permission-check -v
```

At the mailserver there is a mailresponse for an existing ticket which is supposed to be fetched by fetchmail.

If I replace the `--key` with someting else it complains about the key so apparenty I can reach the redmine-server but there is something else wrong.

Questions:

- Where is *vaild email adresses defined*?
- What *info* could be missing?
- Could I create a file with testdata to create a new ticket and what should be in it in that case (instead of the `echo hello` command used above)?